Is it possible to render Angular component dynamically using Selectors?
`Is it possible to render an Angular component dynamically? For example, I have component selector names in my .ts file. When I bind the variable in the .html file using interpolation and innerHTML, the component is not rendering. How can I achieve this?
My component selector structure ->
<app-assessmentitem>
  <app-responsedeclaration>
    <app-correct-response>
    </app-correct-response>
  </app-responsedeclaration>
</app-assessmentitem>

i want to render Angular component dynamically using Selectors`

Yes, you can do thhat with NgComponentOutlet - https://v17.angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet
You have to just pass to it your component's type:
@Component({selector: 'hello-world', template: 'Hello World!'})
export class HelloWorld {}

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component-outlet-simple-example',
  template: `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="HelloWorld"></ng-container>`,
})
export class NgComponentOutletSimpleExample {
  // This field is necessary to expose HelloWorld to the template.
  HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
}

If you want to do that using selectors names specifically, you can simply add some mapper, for example:
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-component-outlet-simple-example',
  template: `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="mapComponentSelectorToComponentType("hello-world")"></ng-container>`,
})
export class NgComponentOutletSimpleExample {

  public mapComponentSelectorToComponentType(selector: string) {
    switch (selector) {
      case 'hello-world':
      return HelloWorld;
      <...put other components you want to handle  in similar way>
    }
}

